# SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context) returns null on postback - provider hosted app

Tags: azure, updatepanel, office365, csom, sharepoint-online

I have a provider hosted app hosted on Azure and installed in SharePoint Online (office 365). While testing the app, I found a strange issue, where if the page remains idle for around 10 mins and then if we change the dropdown values the `SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context)` returns null.

Note: The dropdown change event is a postback and data is retrieved from the list. The `GetSharePointContext` is null only after page remains idle for approx 10 mins. The web page is a form which uses updatepanel, jquery and bootstrap. It is asp.net web application project deployed as website in Azure.

Does the page gets timeout? Is there any configuration that I might be missing?